# What are good resources to learn the basics of graph theory

Tags: neural-network, graphs

I just spent half a day "debugging" a script that tried to get the betweenness centrality of a weighted graph with negative weights. However the package I used for that julia's `LightGraphs` uses Dijkstra's shortest paths, which require non-negative weights as input. I didn't know this, and thus wasted a lot of my and other peoples time trying to find out why my script didn't work.

I the end I found it out. But I figured it would be good to learn some basic graph theory to avoid this kind of problems in the future. Can anybody recommend a good [book|course|other resource] on graph theory? I don't look for a source that rigorously proves all kind of properties, but more of an overview. If I need to know more about a specific graph/test/metric I can always look it up later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two very good resources that may help you to acquire the foundational knowledge on graph theory and complex networks:

- Network Science by Barabasi is you prefer a web tutorial: http://networksciencebook.com/
- The Structure of Complex Networks by Estrada if you prefer a book: https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199591756.001.0001/acprof-9780199591756

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll take a look at those sources!